# Find difference between SQL tables

Tags: mysql, sql, amazon-redshift

Can anyone help me out with syntax to find difference the between two similar tables:

Table 1:

[image]

Table 2:

[image]

I need the difference to be in absolute values like table 1 - table2 = values as output

Comment: What's the expected result?

Comment: values need to show as table1.column1 - table2.column1 the output should be in values just like we do in excel substrating two fiels

Comment: Please add the expected result to the queston using the same format.

Comment: Please share your expected output.

Comment: Tables represent **unordered** sets of rows. Please specify how you want to match rows from the first table with rows on the second table.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have difference of spend,sv and bfe between table1 and table2 for matching channel and funnel you can use inner join.

```
select t1.channel,t1.funnelfunnel,(t1.spend-t2.spend),(t1.sv-t2.sv)sv,(t1.bfe-t2.bfe)bfe
from table1 t1 inner join table2 t2
on t1.channel=t2.channel and t1.funnel=t2.funnel
```

If you want all the rows from table1 with values after subtracting matching values from table2 you can use left join.

```
 select t1.channel,t1.funnelfunnel,(t1.spend-t2.spend),(t1.sv-t2.sv)sv,(t1.bfe-t2.bfe)bfe
    from table1 t1 left join table2 t2
    on t1.channel=t2.channel and t1.funnel=t2.funnel
```

Comment: I don't think this is what the OP wants, but I may be wrong.

Comment: Now I am also thinking that. It's highly possible that you are right.

Comment: Please let me know. If it's not what you are looking for then just please upload your desired output.

Answer (score 0):

The requirement is to find exact matches (cross apply or inner join) and absolute the values and find the difference in values

declare @tmp1 as table(
channel varchar(10),
funnel varchar(2),
spend numeric(18,2),
sv int,
bfe int);

declare @tmp2 as table(
channel varchar(10),
funnel varchar(2),
spend numeric(18,2),
sv int,
bfe int);
insert into @tmp1(channel, funnel, spend, sv, bfe)
values('Display','UF',155629,89554,1669),
('Display','MF',85454,31534,475),
('Display','LF',106983,68324,867)

insert into @tmp2(channel, funnel, spend, sv, bfe)
values('Display','MF',206622.17,38018,21443),
('Display','UF',68219.46,89561,1669),
('Display','LF',2297171.85,514779,59347)

```
select 
tmp1.funnel,
abs(tmp1.spend)-abs(tmp2.spend) spend,
abs(tmp1.sv)-abs(tmp2.sv) sv,
abs(tmp1.bfe)-abs(tmp2.bfe) bfe
from @tmp1 tmp1
join @tmp2 tmp2 on tmp1.funnel=tmp2.funnel
```

output

```
UF  87409.54    -7  0
MF  -121168.17  -6484   -20968
LF  -2190188.85 -446455 -58480
```